# iPhone UIScroll Fixed Background Not Working

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have an iPhone app where I have a view and following hierarchy.

```
View
   ImageView
   ScrollView
      OtherItems
```

I have ImageView background set to an image and ScrollView color to clearColor but still the background is white in simulator and iphone both. Why is that so? Although I can see the background in the IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted XCode and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Check that the image name is exactly correct (case sensitive) and that the image file has been added to the project.

Step 2: Set the imageView image to a color and see if anything changes. If yes, double check step 1. If no, post some code.

Comment: I can see the image in Interface Builder but not in simulator and iphone which means image is set correctly. I tired having ScrollView opacity to 0 and still a white background is there.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your "Other Items" have the background set to whiteColor ... Or you can set the backgroundColor of the scrollView to the image in code.

```
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Also, if you have a large image or your scrollView remains in memory a long time, you shouldn't use the imageNamed: method because it caches the image and drains memory; you should use imageWithContentsOfFile: instead.

```
scroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"image" ofType:@"png"]]];
```

Comment: I have already tried this and end up having background which stretches the image and give bad effect. The image has to be fixed and just UIScrollView must be scrolled.